# How to write send email test case and read Excel file test case in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, sendmail, excel-reader

Here is my my code to write a sample send email test case. When running the code email is not getting triggered. Please find attached data for more details

1. [Login User details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dxvbf.jpg)
2. [Invalid User Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X387W.jpg)
3. [Booking Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVlfg.jpg)

Can anyone please help to resolve the issue as I am novice in selenium automation testing. Below is sample code of my Java code for configuration and triggering of email.

How to send out an Email notification in Selenium webdriver using Java, whenever some scenario is failed/passed in between?

---

```
public class SendEmail {
public SendEmail() {
    }

    public void email() {

        // Create object of Property file
        Properties props = new Properties();

        // this will set host of server- you can change based on your
        // requirement
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");

        // set the port of socket factory
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");

        // set socket factory
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

        // set the authentication to true
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        // set the port of SMTP server
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        // This will handle the complete authentication
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("seleniumtest201@gmail.com", "Admin12!@");
            }
        });
        try {

            // Create object of MimeMessage class
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

            // Set the from address
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("seleniumtest201@gmail.com"));

            // Set the recipient address
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("aniketgupta1993@gmail.com"));

            // Add the subject link
            message.setSubject("Test Case Execution Report");

            // Create object to add multi media type content
            BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();

            // Set the body of email
            messageBodyPart1.setText("This is auto-generated test case execution report");

            // Create another object to add another content
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();

            // Mention the file which you want to send
            String filename = "C://Users//aniket//sampleseleniumproject//test-output//emailable-report.html";

            // Create data source and pass the filename
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);

            // set the handler
            messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));

            // set the file
            messageBodyPart2.setFileName(filename);

            // Create object of MimeMultipart class
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

            // add body part 1
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);

            // add body part 2
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);

            // set the content
            message.setContent(multipart);

            // finally send the email
            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("=====Email Sent=====");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {

            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use following code for the getting email when execution is completed and this put in teardown so you can get an Email notification in selenium webdriver, whenever scenario is failed/passed in between

```
public void tearDown()

{

private static void sendPDFReportByGMail(String from, String pass, String to, String subject, String body) 

{

Properties props = System.getProperties();

String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);

props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);

props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);

props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

try {

    //Set from address

message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

//Set subject

message.setSubject(subject);

message.setText(body);

BodyPart objMessageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

objMessageBodyPart.setText("Please Find The Attached Report File!");

Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

multipart.addBodyPart(objMessageBodyPart);

objMessageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

//Set path to the pdf report file

String filename = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\Default test.pdf";

//Create data source to attach the file in mail

DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);

objMessageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));

objMessageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

multipart.addBodyPart(objMessageBodyPart);

message.setContent(multipart);

Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");

transport.connect(host, from, pass);

transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());

transport.close();

}

catch (AddressException ae) {

ae.printStackTrace();

}

catch (MessagingException me) {

me.printStackTrace();

}

}

}
```